# Golang libvirt guest-agent not available

Tags: go, qemu, libvirt, virsh

I've tried to communicate with the guest agent on a qemu instance through the libvirt golang API. However, it always reject my connections with

```
2022-12-02T00:10:43.799+0100    DPANIC  test/main.go:335    Failed to connect to guest  {"error": "virError(Code=86, Domain=10, Message='Guest agent is not responding: QEMU guest agent is not connected')"}
```

Even if the qemu instance is fully booted and the guest agent is available through the commandline

```
sudo virsh qemu-agent-command test-vm '{"execute":"guest-info"}'
```

Is this a bug in the implementation or do I have to register the agent somewhere in the go code? I wasn't able to find references in the documentation.

```xml
    <channel type='unix'>
      <source mode='bind' path='/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/channel/target/domain-6-test-vm/org.qemu.guest_agent.0'/>
      <target type='virtio' name='org.qemu.guest_agent.0' state='connected'/>
      <alias name='channel0'/>
      <address type='virtio-serial' controller='0' bus='0' port='1'/>
    </channel>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what was the cause in the end. I had a loop and was accessing, or to be more specific try to access, the agent. I changed it to use a timeout of 500ms and not it works.

```go
type qemuStatusResponse struct {
    Return struct {
        Exitcode int    `json:"exitcode,omitempty"`
        OutData  string `json:"out-data,omitempty"`
        Exited   bool   `json:"exited,omitempty"`
        ErrData  string `json:"err-data,omitempty"`
    } `json:"return,omitempty"`
}

func (l *LibvirtInstance) waitForCompletion(ctx context.Context, pid int, domain *libvirt.Domain) (response *qemuStatusResponse, err error) {
    response = &qemuStatusResponse{}

    ticker := time.NewTicker(500 * time.Millisecond)
    defer ticker.Stop()
    for {
        select {
        case <-ticker.C:
            result, err := domain.QemuAgentCommand(
                fmt.Sprintf(`
                {
                    "execute": "guest-exec-status",
                    "arguments": {
                        "pid": %d
                    }
                    }`, pid),
                libvirt.DOMAIN_QEMU_AGENT_COMMAND_BLOCK, 0)
            if err != nil {
                return nil, err
            }
            if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(result), response); err != nil {
                return nil, err
            }
            if response.Return.Exited {
                return response, nil
            }
        case <-ctx.Done():
            return nil, ctx.Err()
        }
    }
}
```

Furhtermore I had some stability issues (i.e., when executing multiple concurrent requests to the connection it was sometimes broken). I found some article in the web suggesting adding the user to the `kvm` group. This worked for me.